# Seems That addJavascriptInterface not work for me when create the container again

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

```
public class MyWebView extends Dialog 
{
    protected WebView mWebView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(),"js2java");

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

}

    public class JavaScriptInterface
    {
        public void test(String response)
        {
            MyToast.showMessage(QWWebView.this.getContext(),response);
        }
    }
```

The first time, show the dialog:

```
new MyWebView().show();
```

The function "test" could be called successfully, then dismiss the MyWebView instance, then show it again:

```
new MyWebView().show();
```

The function "test" could not be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is specifically your issue but I had problems recently with JavaScripInterface when the added the required definition. This is solved by specifically defining which functions are to be used in java script.

```
public class JavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void test(String response)
    {
        MyToast.showMessage(QWWebView.this.getContext(),response);
    }
}
```

Also note a @SuppressWarnings("unused") will get rid of the annoying unused function warning.

In your code example I can't see the point you execute the script?!?

Comment: Not that one, I change the container to activity finally and solved it. Seems that dismiss is just hide the dialog but not destroy it.